# R function and regression

Tags: r

I have the following DF named returns_data:

```
date        Tech   Mining  Banks  Consumer One.Month FFMkt  FFSMB3F FFSMB5F FFHML  FFRMW  
1991-01-01   0.12   0.13    -0.4    0.5       0.01     0.12   0.5    0.9     0.2     0.2
1991-02-01   0.62   0.33    0.4     0.7       0.31     0.42   0.6    0.2     0.7     0.6
1991-03-01   0.12   0.13    -0.4    0.5       0.01     0.12   0.5    0.5   0.8
```

I would like to run several regressions on the following columns, one by one. 
Tech, Mining, Banks and Consumer. I was hoping not o have to copy the code multiple times to do this.

I named this

```
 Portfolio = c (Tech, Mining, Banks, Consumer)
```

I am trying to run the following function

```
RegCoef <- function(returns_data, port_name, factor_choice){
  if(factor_choice == "3F"){
    reg_formula = as.formula(paste(port_name, "- One.Month ~ 
                                   FFMkt +
                                   FFSMB3F + 
                                   FFHML"))
  }else if(factor_choice == "5F"){
    reg_formula = as.formula(paste(port_name, "- One.Month ~ FFMkt + 
                                   FFSMB5F+ 
                                   FFHML + 
                                   FFRMW + 
                                   "))
  }

  reg = lm(reg_formula, data = returns_data)
  summary_output = c(portfolio = port_name, 
    intercept = summary(reg)$coef[1,1],
    intercept_tstat = summary(reg)$coef[1,2],
    summary(reg)$coef[-1, c("Estimate")], 
    Adj.R2 = summary(reg)$adj.r.squared) 

  return(summary_output)
  }
```

I would like to apply the function to the portfolio list

```
Portfolio = c (Tech, Mining, Banks, Consumer)

reg_summary_5F = cbind(sapply(Portfolio, function(port){RegCoef(returns_merged, port, "5F")}))
```

I get the following error message

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = reg_formula, data = returns_data,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'Tech - One.Month.US.Treasury.Bills' In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I am not having much luck. The data has many more rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your function is named "RegCoef" and you call "GetRegCoef" in the sapply, if there is this typo in your code it might be the problem

Comment: @gdevaux - i fixed that up (thank you), but still not luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following changes it's working for me :

```
}else if(factor_choice == "5F"){    
reg_formula = as.formula(paste(port_name, "- One.Month ~ FFMkt + 
                                   FFSMB5F +  
                                   FFHML + 
                                   FFRMW")) # remove extra "+" sign
}
```

## --------

```
Portfolio = c ('Tech', 'Mining', 'Banks', 'Consumer') # strings
```